# Custom WP3.5 Media Uploader WITH sidebar

Tags: wordpress, media, uploader

I have seen countless articles about how to launch a custom version of the WP3.5 Media uploader without the sidebar but cannot for the life of me find anything that actually tells you how to launch it WITH one.

I have modified things quite a bit to allow users to sideload when they use the 'Insert From URL' option and want to enable the 'Insert from URL' option in other areas of my application.

Ideally I'd like this to appear as a third option when viewing the uploader in image mode so you have 'upload files' | 'media library' | 'insert from URL' but failing that I'd just like the side bar to show...

I am currently using this

```
ImageChooser = wp.media.frames.icsImageChooser = wp.media({
            // Set the title of the modal.
            title: 'Choose or Upload Image',

            // Tell the modal to show only images.
            library: {
                type: 'image'
            },
            // Customize the submit button.
            button: {
                // Set the text of the button.
                text: 'Use This'
            }
        });
```

Does any one know what I need to add to that to achieve either of my desired outcomes as described above?

Comment: by sidebar you mean the one on the left that has links insert media, create gallery, etc ?

Comment: Yeah thats the one... made some progress with the details here... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92096/how-can-i-add-the-insert-from-url-tab-to-a-custom-3-5-media-uploader

Comment: But you cannot paste a url into the insert from url input area... I think what I need to do really is add a custom button to the Insert area where you can insert from URL which then does a sideload on the server really since I dont need or want users to be able to add links, alignment or captions...

Comment: I'm using the parameter frame: 'post' to get the "insert from URL" option to appear on the left. As I understand it, the default frame is 'select'. Unfortunately, though I'm able to select from the media library and upload to it, choosing "insert from URL" appears to do nothing; I'm still troubleshooting this. Also, it seems that using the 'post' frame causes wp.media to ignore the 'title' parameter. I imagine it also ignores button text, but I haven't confirmed that.